# c# How to compare int arrays partially

Tags: c#-4.0

I have two int arrays as

```
int[] aArray = {1,2,3,4}
int[] bArray= {1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

I want to check if array bArray has all the elements of aArray in same sequence

anybody knows the better solution?

Comment: Do you mean all the elements in the same order consecutive from the beginning of the array (as the example), consecutive anywhere in the array, or in the same order anywhere in the array (with optional gaps)?

Comment: in same order but anywhere in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to know if the second contains all `int`s of the first array:

```
bool hasBA = aArray.All(bArray.Contains);
```

possibly more efficient using `Except` + `Any`:

```
hasBA = !aArray.Except(bArray).Any();
```

or with `HashSet` which is also efficient:

```
HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>(aArray);
bool isSubset = set.IsSubsetOf(bArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] aArray = {1,2,3,4};
int[] bArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

bool containsAndSameOrder = true; // this is the variable that will let you know if array bArray has all the elements of aArray in same sequence

if (aArray.Length > bArray)
    containsAndSameOrder = false;
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < aArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (aArray[i] != bArray[i])
        {
            containsAndSameOrder = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```